# VueJs: importing custom js libraries

Tags: javascript, vue.js, libraries

I have a VueJS project that I started it with vue-cli webpack. I have a javascript library with functions that I need in all components. I wonder where I need to place this folder and how to call the functions from JSLibrary1 in Component1.vue:

```
-myJSLibrary
    JSLibrary1.js
    JSLibrary2.js
```

JSLibrary1.js

```
var A = A || (function() {
    class B {
        function C(){
            return “hello”;
        }   
    }       
    var obj = new B();
    return obj;
}());
```

Project structure

```
VueProject
   build
   config
   src
    assets
    components
        Component1.vue
    App.vue
    main.js
   static
```

Thanks.

Comment: Since you are using vue-cli, you are probably also using webpack.  Start by taking a look at [Single File Components](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html) and [Webpack: Getting Started](https://webpack.js.org/guides/getting-started/).

Comment: If you have webpack you can use `import` to lnclude external JavaScript code, but your library should also `export` its functions / classes. You could also just load the javascript file with a `<script>` tag in your HTML

Answer (score 11):

libraries.js

```
export const A = () => {
  // your code
}

export const B = () => {
  // your code
}
```

Component1.vue

```
<script>
import { A, B } from '~/path/to/libraries.js'
export default {
  data () {
    return {}
  },
  mounted () {
    // execute A when components is rendered
    A()
  }    
</script>
```

Comment: Good, but.....is there no possibility to use libraries.js in a module without exporting its properties?